# interop word c# set chart height / width

Tags: c#, office-interop

I'm currently working on building a report in c# and then outputting it to word.

I've got the chart building and being populated by data however one thing I cant get my head around is how to set the chart size / height.

any help would be appreciated, spent hours on this seemingly simple task.

CODE:

```
Chart CashflowChart = _document.InlineShapes.AddChart(XlChartType.xlColumnClustered).Chart;

CashflowChart.ChartArea.Height = 100;
```

This results in the following error :

```
{"Not implemented (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004001 (E_NOTIMPL))"}
```

Comment: I suggest you go into Excel manually, record a macro, and make the changes to the chart that you wish. Then go look at the code that was recorded. It'll need a bit of translation, but you can still use the macro code as a guide to write your c# code, as all the object names will be more or less the same.

Comment: Try to use a macro recorder as John suggested. Do you get the same results? Where and when do you run the code? Is it an ASP.NET page?

Answer (score 1):

After hours of messing around and contrary to what msdn docs says you cant edit the chartarea directly, you can edit the chartobject which is the parent of the chartarea :

CashflowChart.Parent.width= 550;
CashflowChart.Parent.height = 150;